# The LINQ expression could not be translated and will be evaluated

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

My code:

```
public static IQueryable<ServicesData> Query(DbContext dbc, string path1 = null, string path2 = null, string path3 = null) =>
    dbc.ServicesData.Where(sd => SQLmatch(sd.Path1, path1) && SQLmatch(sd.Path2, path2) && SQLmatch(sd.Path3, path3));

static bool SQLmatch(string match, string pattern) {
    if (match is null) match = "";
    if (pattern is null) pattern = "";
    bool wildcard = pattern.Contains("%") || pattern.Contains("_");
    return wildcard ? EF.Functions.Like(match, pattern) : object.Equals(match, pattern);
}

using (var dbc = new DbContext()) {
    var q = Query(dbc, "User", "%").ToList();
```

Using latest EFcore 3.0 this fails with:

> Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The
>   LINQ expression 'where ((SQLmatch([sd].Path1, __path1_0) AndAlso
>   SQLmatch([sd].Path2, __path2_1)) AndAlso SQLmatch([sd].Path3,
>   __path3_2))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID
>   'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to the
>   'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
>   'AddDbContext'.

I would appreciate any help with this.

EDIT

It seems the problem is with the function call, if I put the code in SQLmatch into a single expression like this:

```
public static IQueryable<ServicesData> Query(DbContext dbc, string path1 = null, string path2 = null, string path3 = null) =>
    dbc.ServicesData.Where(sd => 
    ((path1 ?? "").Contains("%") || (path1 ?? "").Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like((sd.Path1 ?? ""), (path1 ?? "")) : object.Equals((sd.Path1 ?? ""), (path1 ?? "")))
    && ((path2 ?? "").Contains("%") || (path2 ?? "").Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like((sd.Path2 ?? ""), (path2 ?? "")) : object.Equals((sd.Path2 ?? ""), (path2 ?? "")))
    && ((path3 ?? "").Contains("%") || (path3 ?? "").Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like((sd.Path3 ?? ""), (path3 ?? "")) : object.Equals((sd.Path3 ?? ""), (path3 ?? ""))));
```

it works !

Why can't EFCore process the code in a separate function ?

Comment: Thanks ! Can you explain why it works when the code is embedded without a function call ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the query will be converted to SQL and run in the database server and you can only use those methods in these kinds of queries which are supported by LINQ and can be directly converted to DB functions. So you cannot use your custom functions in these queries, even not all the inbuilt .net methods are supported for LINQ to entities. You can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities) for supported functions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

Comment: please see my edit - the same code works if I don't have it in a separate function

Comment: yes, that is what I'm trying to explain that code would work only if it is in the query directly. It won't work with separate function because LINQ can't convert your custom functions to SQL.